# calculating size of the result and moving files into another folder if it fulfills conditions

Tags: perl

I am trying to calculate distance between protein (`ATOM`) and ligand atoms (`HETATM`). Protein atoms I am obtaining from `pdb` file and ligand atoms I already have seperated in different number of `txt` files. I am using a `substring` to seperate coordinates into an array and I am giving each coordinate name (`x, y and z`). Files that have ligand coordinates look like this:

file 1:

```
HETATM 2244  C1  QWE H 373      17.735 -17.178  22.612  1.00 26.29           C  
HETATM 2245  C2  QWE H 373      18.543 -17.350  21.462  1.00 26.22           C  
HETATM 2246  C3  QWE H 373      19.877 -17.046  21.558  1.00 26.06           C  
HETATM 2247  C4  QWE H 373      20.401 -16.566  22.766  1.00 26.60           C  
HETATM 2248  C4A QWE H 373      19.613 -16.358  23.893  1.00 27.46           C  
HETATM 2249  C5  QWE H 373      20.084 -15.791  25.046  1.00 28.32           C  
HETATM 2250  C6  QWE H 373      19.241 -15.568  26.114  1.00 27.47           C  
HETATM 2251  C7  QWE H 373      17.893 -15.971  26.028  1.00 27.79           C  
HETATM 2252  C8  QWE H 373      17.370 -16.510  24.879  1.00 26.51           C  
HETATM 2253  C8A QWE H 373      18.205 -16.689  23.809  1.00 26.70           C
```

file 2:

```
  HETATM 2225  N   TYS I 363      15.901   2.361  -4.748  1.00 44.75           N  
    HETATM 2226  CA  TYS I 363      16.482   2.005  -3.448  1.00 44.52           C  
    HETATM 2227  CB  TYS I 363      15.434   1.805  -2.340  1.00 42.26           C  
    HETATM 2228  CG  TYS I 363      14.580   3.049  -2.234  1.00 39.78           C  
    HETATM 2229  CD1 TYS I 363      15.156   4.304  -2.015  1.00 37.81           C  
    HETATM 2230  CD2 TYS I 363      13.219   2.924  -2.545  1.00 40.71           C  
    HETATM 2231  CE1 TYS I 363      14.343   5.432  -2.005  1.00 38.74           C
```

Protein cordinates (`ATOM`) that are beeing seperated from `pdb` file look like this:

```
ATOM   2190  O   GLU I 357       7.971  -5.002  -1.496  1.00 41.97           O  
ATOM   2191  CB  GLU I 357       4.752  -5.053  -1.745  1.00 42.96           C  
ATOM   2192  CG  GLU I 357       3.774  -4.690  -2.826  1.00 44.81           C  
ATOM   2193  CD  GLU I 357       3.513  -3.238  -3.102  1.00 46.56           C  
ATOM   2194  OE1 GLU I 357       3.364  -2.632  -2.025  1.00 45.88           O  
ATOM   2195  OE2 GLU I 357       3.416  -2.667  -4.193  1.00 47.58           O
```

I have written a script that will calculate distances between these protein and ligand atoms and if result of fulfills specific condition it should move `ligand txt files` into another folder.

This is how part of results look like:

```
QWE#I#363.txt
16
11.2
2.40023269705252
3.77980634424569
4.84684722267991
4.8225354327366
4.96742287308016
5.0893916139358
5.44698035612393
5.53698961530541
5.69511940173338
6.58882887924706
8.17976515555306
8.36770577876636
8.60629182633264
8.94395818415985
4.50089380012459
5.57823843161979
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Glob;

mkdir "covalently_bound";
mkdir"5<dist>2";
mkdir"5<dist>4";
mkdir"6<dist>5"

for my $pdbs (glob '*pdb')
{
    printf "%s\n", $pdbs;
    open my $pdb, "<" ,$pdbs;

    while (my $pdb_lines = <$pdb>)
    {
        chomp($pdb_lines);

        if($pdb_lines=~/^ATOM /)
        {
            my @prot_atoms= split '\t', $pdb_lines;
            #print "@prot_atoms\n";
            my @pdb_coord = (substr($pdb_lines, 30, 8),substr($pdb_lines,38,8),substr($pdb_lines,46,8));
            #print "@pdb_coord\n";
            my $x = substr($pdb_lines, 30, 8);
            my $y = substr($pdb_lines,38,8);
            my $z = substr($pdb_lines,46,8);

            foreach my $txt (glob '*txt')
            {
                printf "%s\n", $txt;
                open my $fh, "<" ,$txt;
                my @lines= <$fh>;
                my $file_sz = scalar@lines;
                print "$file_sz\n";
                #print "@lines\n";
                my $c;

                for ($c=0; $c<=$#lines; $c++)
                {
                    chomp ($lines[$c]);

                    if ($lines[$c] =~ m/^HETATM/)
                    {   
                         my @lig_atoms= split '\t', $lines [$c];
                         #print "@lig_atoms\n";
                         my @lig_coord = (substr($lines [$c], 30, 8),substr($lines [$c],38,8),substr($lines [$c],46,8));
                         #print "@lig_coord\n";
                         my $x1 = substr($lines [$c],30, 8);
                         my $y1 = substr($lines [$c],38,8);
                         my $z1 = substr($lines [$c],46,8);

                         my $dist = sqrt( ($x-$x1)**2 + ($y-$y1)**2 + ($z-$z1)**2 );
                         print "$dist\n";
                         #my $dist_sz = ?;     #Here I am not sure how to calculate the size of the result and to include it into if loop.

                         if ($dist < 2)
                         {
                             close ($fh);   
                             system ("mv $txt covalently_bound");
                             last;
                         }

                         if ($dist_sz >= 70% and 4<$dist>2 )
                         {
                             system ("mv $txt 4<dist>2");
                         }

                         if ($dist_sz >= 70% and 5<$dist>4)
                         {
                             system ("mv $txt 5<dist>4");
                         }

                         if ($dist_sz >= 70% and 6<$dist>5)
                         {
                             system ("mv $txt 6<dist>5");
                         } 
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Script is working, I don't get any error but I am encountering two problems that I don't know how to solve:

`1st:`

I want to calculate the distance between each ligand atom (`HETATM`) and all protein atoms (`ATOM`). So, `HETATM1` with `ATOM1`; `HETATM2` with `ATOM1`; `HETATM3` with `ATOM1` and so on.

`2nd:`

The result of distances should be huge for each calculation (or for each ligand file). I want to check what is the size of each result and to set up a condition that if more then `70%` of the result gives values between different numbers then move it into another directory.

I have no idea how should I do these two things, been struggling for a few days, if anybody can help or give some suggestion I would appreciate it!

Comment: For calculating your distances, [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186656/calculating-distances-between-protein-and-ligand/48193214#48193214) looks kinda similar to what you're trying to do? E.g. `sqrt ( ( X-X1) ** 2 + (y-y1) **2 + ( z -z1 ) **2 )`

Comment: Haven't you been told enough times how disrespectful it is to post such badly-formatted code? And why are you using two separate accounts at the same time?

Comment: @Borodin I have no idea who milan is and I am not using two accounts. Many people are doing the same things...

Comment: @Sobrique The question is not the same and this is not the answer to my question, I am doing something different, but the principe is the same. Formula is the same, everybody uses this formula, but the input with different number of files is different and conditions are different and way of extracting coordinates is different.

Comment: even if you're not Milan, you should indent properly your code. You shouldn't do it because it is respectful to us, but you should do it for you. It is much easier to read a well indented code that your current one.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to change it to look better. I have tried to organize it the best I could, each loop except last small one I devided so it can be easier to read, I also matched all brackets.

Comment: why don't you put your brackets right under `for, while, if` key words? why do you put a tab? Also you should not put your block content right under the brackets, here use tab. put some white lines between your serie of  `if`s ...  I don't know, some basic indentation rules. also, there're some random tabs everywhere. why?

Comment: But have a look, my brackets are right under `for,while and if loop`, arent they? Because if I dont put a tab then all closing brackets will be in the same line at the end..

Comment: `perltidy -pbp` is incredibly useful for formatting code. It applies a set of 'best practice' formatting guidelines. (You can configure them to meet a house style, but precisely what style you're using doesn't really matter).

Comment: @Sobrique I see, Thank you, I will make use of it!

Comment: wait wait wait, you have to put brackets right under the `for while ...` I mean the bracket directly under the `f w ...` then you put a tab at the line right under the bracket. until the end of the block. Honnestly I don't see what's so complicated

Comment: basicly put a tab at the start of each block, 2 tabs if you're in a sub-bluck, 3 tabs in a sub-sub block, ...  (i mean, number of tabs from the left side of the sheet)

Comment: @Flying_whale it is not complicated I just didn't know that that way it will look better and I have many loops.. I will do it next time..

Comment: That's precisely because you have many loops that you have to indent properly, try to edit your code in your post to make it look better ;)

Comment: @Flying_whale Thanks man for this these useful info, I will edit it know :)

Comment: @Flying_whale I have changed it, hope it looks a bit better now :)

Comment: @djordje that is much better indeed :)  you only forgot to indent your first `while` and your first `if`, so you will have to add other tabs on the rest of your lines ;)

Comment: (your first `while` at the same level of `open ... `  your first `if` at the same level of the `chomp`) keep in mind that each line at the same nesting level must be at the same level of indentation

Comment: @Flying_whale Hope it looks even better now :) I didn't indent each `if loop` at the end because there are to much, so I just put whitespace to can be easier to read.

Comment: @djordje your indentation is fine now, don't you find your code easier to read? ;)

Comment: @Flying_whale Yes I do, it is much easier to read now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @djordje: Really? Then it's astonishing that your opening sentence is almost identical, including the grammar mistakes.